# How does the pygame function pygame.rect.fit() work?

Tags: python, pygame

I was trying to resize a rectangle in pygame when my player lose health, and I was trying to find some function that can do that, when I ran into this function. How exactly does it work? The pygame documentation is a bit vague regarding what inputs does it take and what function it serves, and I failed to find anything examples online as well.

Comment: To me the documentation seems pretty clear. You could always look at the [source code](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/blob/19b0c898a7f881ac598b5ddc7114b181c812943b/src_c/rect.c#L1016) if you want. But basically it just grows or shrinks one rectangle so that it'll be no bigger than another rectangle, while preserving aspect ratio. So basically, if you had a rectangle that was 100x100, and one that was 50x25, it'd grow the 50x25 rectangle to 100x50 - the aspect ratio would still be 2:1, but it would then fit exactly within the 100x100 one. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. My previous understanding was that I shrink one rectangle to the coordinates of (x, y), but it only took one argument, which was kind of confusing for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pygame.Rect.fit(Rect) -> Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.fit) scales a rectangle. It changes the width and height of the rectangle on the same scale. The only argument to this function is a rectangle, which defines the maximum size of the scaled rectangle.
You can use this function to scale an image. For example, if you want to scale a background image to `fit` your screen but don't want to change the aspect ratio of the background image, you can use this function.

```py
screen = pygame.dispaly.set_mode((800, 600))
background = pygame.image.load('my_background.jpg')

screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
background_rect = background.get_rect().fit(screen_rect)
background = pygame.transform.scale(background, background_rect.size)
```

Comment: Thank you! Does this function work on other rectangles as well? For example, if I wanna scale a rectangle based on the scale of another rectangle.

Comment: @RichardSu What is a "other rectangle"? This function works with [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect) objects. (`Surface.get_rect()` returns a `pygame.Rect` object)